# Why does this matrix multiplication code not work

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int ar1[3][3] = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
int ar2[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int ar3[3][3];
int i,j,k;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    ar3[i][j] = 0;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
        for(k=0;k<3;k++)
        {
            ar3[i][j] = ar3[i][j]+(ar1[i][k]*ar2[k][j]);
        }
    }
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++);
    printf("%d\t",ar3[i][j]);
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code in Dev C++ it does not give any error but fails to run and the application stops working. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages! This looks like C!

Comment: @Olaf: He's using a C++ compiler.  The code is (except for the bug) valid C++.  Please [do not retag based on (lack of) API usage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252433/103167)

Comment: `for(j=0;j<3;j++);` is probably not what you want, remove the `;`.

Comment: Stop the retagging and read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287495/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm no clairvoyant. Where do I miss this is not compiled as C? AFAIK Dev C++ is an IDE which can be used for C and C++ code development, so mentioning that IDE is no hint about the language used. And it just uses C constructs.

Comment: @Olaf If you're no clairvoyant - why do you "know" that OP is scompiling the code as C and not C++? As pointed out the code is valid as both C and C++. The only thing against it is use of uninitialized variable as index, and the inclusion of `stdio.h`, but then the validity as a C program would be invalidated as well, and inclusion of non-standard header (`conio.h`) indicates that another non-standard header could be OK.

Comment: @skyking: Occams razor.

Comment: This is valid C++, but people are not using things like arrays and printf in C++ much any more. You may want to invest some time in learning modern C++. (Assuming C++ is your sort of thing since the question is tagged C++).

Comment: @Olaf Occams razor could be used to conclude that this is C++...

Comment: @skyking: Please elaborate. DevC++ is not a compiler, but an IDE with a badly choosen name. It uses the gcc which can be used for C and C++ code, as can the IDE. The code itself uses C programming style for I/O, the rest is ambivalent.

Comment: move ar3[i][j] = 0; inside the j-loop

Comment: @Olaf One could assume that DevC++ is aimed primarily at C++. For example a tutorial at youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr7xtjVGEc4) shows when starting a new project that "C++ project" is selected by default. Is it then the simplest explanation that the OP must have changed the default to "C project"? I don't think so.

Comment: @skyking: Considering the coding style clearly does invoke the impression OP waht to program C code. But as he did not clarify, he seems not to be interested in this question. Same for me; it's not worth the time. Feel free to add some final assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

On the line

```
ar3[i][j] = 0;
```

`j` is still garbage so you get *undefined behavior*, which may lead to different kinds of faults - erroneous results, segfaults, on some rare cases it may even work as expected.

Move that line inside the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

you should initialize `arr3[i][j]` to `0` as `int arr3[i][j]={0};`. Also while displaying the multiplication matrix you closed the second loop with `j`. Don't close that otherwise you won't get desired output. I corrected it. Hope this one solves your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int ar1[3][3] = {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
int ar2[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int ar3[3][3] = {0}; // here goes initialization
int i,j,k;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
  {
    for(k=0;k<3;k++)
    {
        ar3[i][j] = ar3[i][j]+(ar1[i][k]*ar2[k][j]);
    }
  }
}
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<3;j++)
    {
    printf("%d\t",ar3[i][j]);
    }
  printf("\n");
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your version still has the wild write which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: oh yes actually i didn't looked at that. Thanks btw that won't change the answer coz j=3 and a[i][3] don't exitst. Still thanks for correcting

Comment: `j` will equal `3` only after a pass of internal cycle, if program somehow survives a write to somewhere like `a[i][-100500]`, which is unlikely.

Comment: yup for the first time. thanks